# How do I loop back to only a certain section?

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a login function where the user enters their username and if it's wrong it loops back and asks them to enter it again. Same thing for their password.

```
print('kindly key in your username')
while True: 
    username = input()
    if username != 'tom':
        print ('wrong username, please key in your username again')
        continue
    else:
        print('key in your password')
        password = input()
        if password != '1234':
            print('wrong password, key again')
        else:
            print('access granted')
```

How can I ask the user to re-enter their password if they type it wrong their first try? Right now this code loops all the way back to asking the user to enter their username if they enter the wrong password.

Answer (score 2):

You'll just need either an inner `while` loop, or write a helper function to get user input:

```py
def user_input(prompt, target_response):
    while True:
        user_response = input(prompt + "\n > ")
        if user_response != target_response:
            print("Incorrect input! Please try again!")
            continue
        return user_response
```

Then you can reuse this function to get the username:

```py
username = user_input("Kindly key in your username", "tom")
password = user_input("Please enter your password", "1234")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write two separate while loops and break out of each when you get the desired result:

```
print('kindly key in your username')
while True:
    username = input()
    if username != 'tom':
        print('wrong username, please key in your username again')
    else:
        break

print('key in your password')
while True:
    password = input()
    if password != '1234':
        print('wrong password, key again')
    else:
        break

print('access granted')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can jump to arbitary positions inside a loop in Python. We could do that in older languages like C and C++ using `goto`, but this practice is generally frowned upon as it makes the code harder to read and understand. For this reason most of the newer languages don't provide `goto`.

Your code has another logical error as well. You are not breaking out of the loop even if you input the correct credentials and it will run infinitely, asking you for the credentials again and again.

One thing that you could do is to break up your code into 2 parts, like this:

```
print('kindly key in your username')
while True: 
    username = input()
    if username != 'tom':
        print ('wrong username, please key in your username again')
    else:
        break

while True:
        print('key in your password')
        password = input()
        if password != '1234':
            print('wrong password, key again')
        else:
            print('access granted')
            break
```

Also as @blorgon pointed out, since you are repeating the same kind of action twice, i.e taking input and checking whether it is correct, you could turn that into a function to keep your code DRY.

Comment: I appreciate this, and all the help! thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just like you used a while for the whole situation, you can put in a `while` loop just for the password part,

```py
print('kindly key in your username')
while True: 
    username = input()
    if username != 'tom':
        print ('wrong username, please key in your username again')
        continue
    else:
        print('key in your password')
        while True:
            password = input() 
            if password != '1234':
                print('wrong password, key again')
                continue
            else:
                print('access granted')
                break
```

Additionally, you can avoid the `if` conditionals by directly using the conditions in the `while` loop, instead of `while True`.